# Is there a name for the inner part of the elbow?

Tags: selección-de-palabras

Is there a name in Spanish for the inner part of the elbow (on the opposite side of the part we call "elbow")? If not, how would it best be described?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there's a name (although not very commom): *sangradura* o *sangría*. Here are the (relevant part of the) definitions according to the DRAE:

> [sangradura](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?LEMA=sangradura).
>
> 1. f. Parte hundida del brazo opuesta al codo.

```
`
```

> [sangría](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltGUIBusUsual?TIPO_HTML=2&LEMA=sangr%EDa).
>
> 3 . f. Parte de la articulación del brazo opuesta al codo.

Although those are the "official" names, they are rarely used and it's usual to refer to this part (at least in Colombia) as *el pliegue del codo*.

Comment: I think I had never heard or read those words with that meaning in Spain

Comment: It is common in medical circles because as the name indicates its where you get blood. "Sangradura"=(bleeding spot) and "sangreria"=(bleeding mess)